# Filling a region

Tags: tikz-pgf

Another day, another problem! This time i can't understand why, after filling, tikz leaves a white space like this

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (I) at (12,0);

\coordinate (C1) at (4,0);
\coordinate (C2) at (7,0);

\draw ($ (O)+(-1,0) $) -- ($ (I)+(1,0) $);%asse ottico

\draw [very thick] (C1)++(75:-3) node (A1) {A1} arc (75:-75:-3) node (B1) 
{B1};
\draw [very thick] (C2)++(75:3) node (A2) {A2} arc (75:-75:3) node (B2) {B2};

\begin{scope}
\clip (C1)++(75:-3) arc (75:-75:-3) -- (A2) -- (C2)++(75:3) arc (75:-75:3) -- 
(A1);
\filldraw [color=lightgray, opacity=0.6] (-10,-10) rectangle (20,10);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need even `clip` here. The problem is that you use the increment `++` in the path. You can do that for the first coordinate, but if you do this for the others, the path has "jumps". Yet, as you are loading `calc`, you could just do

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (I) at (12,0);

\coordinate (C1) at (4,0);
\coordinate (C2) at (7,0);

\draw ($ (O)+(-1,0) $) -- ($ (I)+(1,0) $);%asse ottico

\draw [very thick] (C1)++(75:-3) node (A1) {A1} arc (75:-75:-3) node (B1) 
{B1};
\draw [very thick] (C2)++(75:3) node (A2) {A2} arc (75:-75:3) node (B2) {B2};

\fill[color=lightgray, opacity=0.6](C1)++(75:-3) arc (75:-75:-3) 
-- ($(C2)+(75:3)$) arc (75:-75:3) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, as you already have named nodes, you could simplify this to

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\coordinate (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate (I) at (12,0);

\coordinate (C1) at (4,0);
\coordinate (C2) at (7,0);

\draw ($ (O)+(-1,0) $) -- ($ (I)+(1,0) $);%asse ottico

\draw [very thick] (C1)++(75:-3) node (A1) {A1} arc (75:-75:-3) node (B1) 
{B1};
\draw [very thick] (C2)++(75:3) node (A2) {A2} arc (75:-75:3) node (B2) {B2};

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[color=lightgray, opacity=0.6](A1.center)  arc (75:-75:-3) -- 
    (A2.center) arc (75:-75:3) -- cycle ;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here I also put the fill on the `background layer`.

Comment: I named nodes just to focus them, they are irrilevant for my picture

Comment: @user203430 The first option only uses the named coordinates `C1` and `C2`.

Comment: Schrödinger's cat is right ! it's preferable to name nodes. Firstly you simply and then it's more easy to modify. Too many coordinates kill the code